# php artisan storage

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

When I worked on laravel local development server php artisan storage:link works fine for me. But when I transfer my site to production server then I saw my public storage link was a folder. Then I delete that tried to create a link. I got an error because my app was in the root folder and tried to solve this problem, but problem not solved, i m using hostinger server.(hpanel)

Comment: It doesn't look like you finished your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Right now your question is very unclear. I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow and read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources exist to help you have a good experience here, so please use them. Thanks.